# For what integral values of $x$ is $\left|x^{3}-6x^{2}+11x-6\right|$ prime?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

> For what integral values of $x$ is $\left|x^{3}-6x^{2}+11x-6\right|$ prime?

I have tried making the graph of this function, which is doable, but that does not help in finding if the function attains a prime value for an **integral** $x$. how do i go about solving this problem.

Possible approach:
We know that a prime number can be expressed as $6n-1$ or $6n+1$, but i don't know how to proceed further. Need suggestions or hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The expression can be factorised as $|(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)|.$

Can you continue?

Comment: so we can say that since product of three consecutive integers is always divisible by 2, so we cannot get a prime number for integer x?

Comment: Unless the product is $2$ itself. But that isn't possible here.